# Available data about 'likers' as a page on Facebook

Tags: social-network-analysis

I am hoping to model the characteristics of the users of a specific page on Facebook, which has roughly 2 million likes. I have been looking at the Facebook SDK/API, but I can't really see if what I would like to do is possible. It seems that the users share quite different amounts of data so I probably discard a lot of users and only use the ones with a quite open public profile. I would like to have the following data:

1) See the individuals that have 'liked' the page.

2) See the list of friends for each person that have 'liked' the page.

3) See gender for each person (optional)

4) See other pages that each person has liked (optional)

Could anyone tell me if it is possible to get this data? As mentioned earlier it is okay if I discard data for users that don't like to share this data.

Comment: AFAIK you have to buy that data. The FB api is more for interacting with the platform not for retrieving personal info of users that use the service.

Answer (score 3):

Want to wish you good luck. Some time ago faced with the same problem, but didn't find any satisfying solution. 
First of all, there is no way to get list of users, who "liked" a particular page. Even, if you are an administrator of this page (I was). One only can get list of last 3 or 5 hundred users.

Friendships data for most of the users is also inaccessible. Looks like gender is the only thing from your list, that you can get.

Data about pages, that exact user "likes", should be available (as it's written in docs), but in reality, through API you can collect something only for friends and FoF. Even though this data is available through web interface. So the only way is to try dirty trick with parsing and scraping (but remember, that I didn't advise it ;) ).

Comment: This is more of a comment than answer.

Comment: Will move it to comments ASAP.